# Ideal column widths in less

Tags: command-line, less

Is there a way to emulate/improve on the behavior of BSD's `column -t` in `less`? i.e. to set the value of `less -x/--tabs=...` automatically so that each column is 2 characters wider than the widest encountered value in this column?

Comment: Why not `column -t ... | less`?

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, but native support would be more practical, if it exists

Comment: Why do you think it would be more practical? I don't think so. In `Unix` there should be many small programs doing simple things and doing complex things together.

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion, but I don't think that `vi`, `emacs` or even `nano` are simple at all. I would argue that `less` is already a text user interface with advanced functionalities anyway; if I wanted absolute simplicity I'd stick with `head`, `tail` & `sed`.

Comment: I know it's a matter of opinion, I expressed mine. Now, if you think that `less` should have this option nothing stops you from adding it and sending a patch to the maintainers.

Comment: No offense intended. For now I'm just asking if it exists. If it's confirmed that it doesn't, then I might start thinking about adding it.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following command, and it works wonders displaying tabular data. It is saved as a function in my environment, and it can take data from stdin and file paths. I like this feature because, with awk, I can filter out the information I don't care about in large text files and then send it to a reader.

```
powerReader() { column -t -s$'\t' "$@" | less -S; }
```